# i was told that you need to make it more dynamic code !! ..how?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have given file path for chrome driver...but its static wat if any one wants to run the same script on different system ,again they need to configure path and all.can you all tell me how to solve this

```
problem.System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe") ,
```

i was told that you need to make it more dynamic !! ..how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use properties file. Search in Google to know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it like below :-

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
```

As you can see I have started code here from `./src` , It means from src file of your project. so where ever you project is deployed the location will be the same.

There is one more thing to take care. if you are using windows then use backward slash `\\` and if you are using mac or linux then use forward slash `//` for setting up the path.

Another way is that you can use :-

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

This code will give the path of present directory of project. You can append your path by using String concatenation like below:-

```
String externalPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/lib";
```

Note:- All binaries put inside your project folder. It will help you to avoid many errors

Or

You can create a property file for your automation project and define all path you need for same:-

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-properties-file.html

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to see, getAbsolutePath. It will give you the default path of workspace independent of machine. you can add file / class name with that. Put some effort. If you cant, ping me I will put the code here. Thanks.